# Show/Hide div on image click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, toggle

If you go to http://oandg.co.uk.s156312.gridserver.com/#work and select a portfolio item and click 'More' you will see an image and a text box with a little 'i' in the corner.

I would like to make it so if you clicked the little 'i' the text box would disappear and if you clicked it again it would show.

I tried this but it does nothing:

```
$(function() {
$(".openBoxButton").click(function() {
      $('#colorbox').fadeIn(1200);
       $.colorbox(); 
         $('.rsABlock img.info').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('.caption-background').toggleClass('hidden');
       });
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Slide One -->
<div id="simple-slider-one" class="royalSlider rsDefault" style="width: 100%;">
    <a class="rsImg" href="images/Froosh/froosh1.jpg">  
        <div class="rsABlock">
            <img src="images/info.svg" alt="" class="info">
            <div class="caption-background">
                <h4>What we did for them</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem distinctio deserunt nostrum illum dolor obcaecati eaque ipsam! Distinctio, ipsa accusamus saepe temporibus ex pariatur possimus quidem sapiente obcaecati labore iusto.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="rsImg" href="images/Froosh/froosh2.jpg">  
        <div class="rsABlock">
            <img src="images/info.svg" alt="" class="info">
            <div class="caption-background">
                <h4>What we did for them</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem distinctio deserunt nostrum illum dolor obcaecati eaque ipsam! Distinctio, ipsa accusamus saepe temporibus ex pariatur possimus quidem sapiente obcaecati labore iusto.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Provide the HTML here as well. As soon as your problem is fixed on your URL, this won't be helpful for someone else. Too localized.

Comment: `toggleClass('hidden')` is unnecessary unless there's some special CSS rules I don't know about -- `$('.caption-background').toggle()` does the same

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $(".openBoxButton").click(function () {
        $('#colorbox').fadeIn(1200);
        $.colorbox();
    });

    $('.rsABlock').on('click', 'img.info', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.caption-background').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

EDIT: Just to add some explanation of this, you were previously adding a click handler on every click of the ".openBoxButton" class - now I did NOT search for that class in your page but placing this outside that function prevents the event hanlder from being repeatedly added.

EDIT based on comment: I tested using developer tools and it works.  #colorBox does not seem to work - likely added/removed cycle or something.

```
 $(document).on('click', 'img.info', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.caption-background').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't seem to work either - as this is being loaded into the DOM after initial load will this be stopping the code functioning?

Comment: Find another anchor that IS present on initial load other than the `.rsABlock` class - worst case `$(document).on(`

Comment: Even if I use #colorbox as the anchor (always in the DOM) it doesn't work because surely the .caption-background and img.info is added after the DOM has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Yes... You can do that with CSS:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/285/275" class="portfolio" alt="">
    <div class="mask">
         <h2>Froosh</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem nostrum     porro iste excepturi vel ducimus cumque minima rem voluptates cum!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
/* CSS */
.container {
    /* Some width */
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
}
.container img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.container .mask {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* some color */
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    /* Firefox 4-15 */
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    /* Opera 10.50–12.00 */
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}
.container:hover .mask {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

There is a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KaCHN/1/

**Is up to you put some style on the `.mask` element**

Comment: You can use the JS provided in other answers in order to have an IE/Old Browsers fallback...

Comment: I'm not sure you have understood my problem - the thumbnails work fine. It is once you click 'More' (after hovering over a thumbnail) that you will see what I am talking about

Comment: No this is still to do with the portfolio images which are fine - go to the website hover over a thumbnail then click the red circle which says 'More' - then you'll see my problem

Comment: Yes my friend, click on the more button in the JsFiddle.

Comment: Go to the site you mention and put this code in the console, if this is what you want then I will update my answer: `$('img.info').on('click', function() {var caption = $(this).siblings("div.caption-background"); caption.toggle(); }).css("cursor","pointer");`

Comment: Oh sorry, I was looking on a iPhone and the info circle wasn't showing. I have just put that code into the console and it changes the cursor etc but doesn't make it disappear?