# How to show/hide div click on image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show/hide div when the user clicks on it. I found fiddle but it works on input, I want to integrate with Image. Please help me.

```css
#content {
  display: none;
}
input[type="text"]{
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="text"]:focus{
    outline: none;
}
input:focus + div#content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="CLICK TO SHOW CONTENT">
<div id="content">
and the content will show.
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean ? Do you want an image to appear instead of the text ?

Comment: Welcome on SO : please [always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931562/show-hide-div-by-clicking-image) [do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472783/show-and-hide-div-on-click-on-image) [a search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971616/show-hide-div-on-image-click-not-working) before posting on SO.

Comment: Like dis: https://jsfiddle.net/gkb1u4L7/4/

Answer (score 0):

Just showing an image instead of the text should work.

```
<input type="text" value="CLICK TO SHOW CONTENT">
<div id="content">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZCbBNIt.png">
and the content will show.
</div>
```

See : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8rg9za4/)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job.

EDIT: I have attached the event listener on body instead of image, so that the event can be detected. You can make changes to optimize the code, as what I have given is very naive.

```js
var isVisible = false;

function toggleDivDisplay(event) {
    var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");
    if (isVisible) {
        contentDiv.style.display = "none";
        isVisible = !isVisible;
    }
    else if(event != undefined && 
            'target' in event && 
            event.target.id == "imgId") {
        contentDiv.style.display = "block";
        isVisible = !isVisible;
    }
}

document.body.onclick = toggleDivDisplay;
```

```css
#content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img id="imgId" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marvelcinematicuniverse/images/3/35/IronMan-EndgameProfile.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/2000?cb=20190423175213" height="50" width="50" onclick="toggleDivDisplay()">
<div id="content"> 
The content will show.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply, actually it working fine but here is small problem actually I need when user click on image it will show content when user click on window it will hide the content.

Comment: I just want to hide text, if user click on whitespace or window

Comment: Made the changes according to what you have asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
#content {
    display: none;
}
img{
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
img:focus{
    outline: none;
    
}
img:focus + div#content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png' tabindex="0"/>
<div id='content'>
    and the content will show.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, I have created with jquery, it is working fine.

```
   <img src='https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png' tabindex="0" class="imgClick "/>
    <div id='content'>
        and the content will show.
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('.imgClick').click(function(){
                $('#content').toggle();                                
            });
        });
    </script>
```